# Use jQuery to Add Values of Multiple <select> Boxes

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form that has multiple select drop downs. i.e.

```
Item 1: 
<select name="premier1">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
<br />
Item 2:
<select name="premier2">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
<br />
Item 3: 
<select name="premier3">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
```

Basically What I would like to do would be to use jQuery to add the values of all the premiere  drop downs together and provide the total to another `<div>` tag somewhere on the page.

Comment: OK, so do it. If there's a problem, what is it? What have you tried? And a "tag" is the text `"<div>"`; you probably mean "node".

Comment: Safe to assume you want only the selected values added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the selected values, you could use the the [`attribute-starts-with-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to get `<select>` elements that start with "premier":

```
var total = 0;

$('select[name^="premier"]').val(function(i,val){total += +val; return val;});

alert( total );
```

...then pass a function directly to the [`val()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method, which gives you the current value of each selected option in the `val` parameter.

Inside the function, it uses the unary `+` operator to convert it from a string to a number, and adds it to your total.

---

**EDIT:** It appears as though returning `undefined` clears the value. This seems inconsistent with other parts of the API where I'm pretty sure returning `undefined` has no effect.

I fixed it by doing `return val;`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ssyyX/

Comment: `val()` is not an iterator. It will set the value of the elements based on what the function will return, which in this case is `undefined`.

Comment: @Shef: Sure it is. With no return value, it doesn't set anything. **EDIT:** Correction, you're right about it setting the value based on `undefined`. This behavior seems inconsistent with other iterators where there's no effect if you return `undefined`. I fixed it.

Comment: Still won't work. `val()` is not an iterator. In addition, you are all iterating over the wrong elements.

Comment: @Shef: Why do you keep saying that `.val()` is not an iterator? It is when you pass it a function. Just click my example. And what do you mean by the wrong elements? This gets the value from each selected `<option>`.

Comment: Do you even understand what you are doing on your code??? You are changing the value of the select box instead of just reading it. This is totally wrong, and will bring so many headaches, especially if you are using a pub/sub.

Comment: @Shef: I absolutely understand. Obviously you must not. It is simply an alternate way of iterating the elements while being provided the current value in the form of an argument to the function. Why is that difficult to understand? Did you click the example and see that it works?

Comment: ...by the way, it worked with my original answer, but it had a side effect. jQuery's API seems inconsistent in that it clears the value if the function returns `undefined`, where it doesn't behave that way with other similar methods.

Comment: Well Using this as a launching pad I got it to work exactly how I wanted it to work.... you can check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/PrinceofVegas/3ahHQ/

Comment: @Prince: Looks great. Only thing I'd suggest is to cache the set of `select` elements so you don't need to keep selecting them from the DOM. Just a little more efficient that way. http://jsfiddle.net/3ahHQ/1/ And of course you could use `.each()` to iterate, and grab the value using `.val()` inside the loop as an alternative if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var total = 0;
$('select[name^="premier"]').val(function(i,e){ total += +e; });
```

Comment: This won't work. You're performing string concatenation, and trying to call `.val()` against a DOM element.

Comment: corrected. no return appears neccessary. btw, epic arguments over this one. so much for working together for a solution.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did originally, but there seems to be an inconsistency in the API, where this will have a side effect of *clearing* the current value. Other jQuery methods that accept a function don't behave this way. I had to fix it by returning the current value.

Comment: I see, good catch. I don't normally iterate with val(), but I like the idea of using for certain things

Comment: Yeah, it's a very handy way to iterate when you only need the value of the argument that's provided, but this one presents that unfortunate inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using javascript itself. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript/1085810#1085810)

Instead of using getElementById use getElementByName. Get all the values and add them.

Answer (score 0):

```
var total;

$('select').each(function(){
    total += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
});

$('#total_display').text(total);
```

1. Make a variable to hold total
2. Go through each `select` and add it's value to the total
3. Display the total in another area

Comment: Won't work if there are selects with other names or IDS in the page. charlie Brown's solution is more complete.

Comment: A) I've provided code that will work for the sample code that was posted. and B) Charlie Brown's code does not expressly set the value to an integer which risks concatenating strings and C) Charlie Brown's code does not set the total to another element on the page, as the original poster requested.

Comment: @idrumgood, Agreed and upvoted. Was just looking at a general answer, no offence.

Answer (score -1):

[The <strike>only</strike> assumed working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/7ezQG/). :)

```
var total = 0;
$('select[name^="premier"]').each(function(){ 
    total += +this.value; 
});
$('#total_holder span').text(total);
```

Comment: You're correct, i needed the + operator... but your solution adds all values, not selected values. Although the poster doesn't specify, it would seem to make more sense.

Comment: Only working solution? Nope. And do you really think OP wants the sum of adding 0-9 3 times over? If that's the case, there's no need for DOM selection. Certainly he wants to add the selected values of each drop down.

Comment: Shef: I still think you need to target the selected options, and not all the option values. (Not my down-vote by the way.)